# How to stream RTMP audio in Android?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, rtmp

I've googled many times to see how to stream RTMP audio in Android. However, I don't get success.

Therefore, if anyone has good solutions, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: try this https://github.com/ajeet17181/mplayer-android... its for video but i think it will help you..

Comment: I've tried with the "MPlayer.apk", but it doesn't work even local file.

Comment: Have you considered [ijkplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer)?