# How to stream RTMP audio purely by ffmpeg in Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, live-streaming, aac

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265269/how-to-stream-rtmp-audio-in-android) is a same question, but has no answer.

[cineio-broadcast-android](https://github.com/cine-io/cineio-broadcast-android) is a great project for the RTMP video streaming, but how to stream RTMP audio purely ?

There is little information about it. Any suggestion is prefered.

Comment: RTMP streaming for audio is just the same as it is for video, although the data you're passing will not include a video stream, just an audio stream.
From what i'm seeing on this project, you will have to overwrite the `config.selectCamera("back");` method which probably set both audio (microphone) and video (back camera) streams

Comment: @EladG I mean no camera preview, just audio.

Comment: You're looking for an already made project which does exactly this? because you can just take the camrea preview & the video stream out of this implementation and you will have exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @EladG I tried. But after removing the camera preview & video stream, I got the error: `Fatal signal 8 (SIGFPE) at 0x00003b21 (code=-6), thread 15206 (FFmpeg)`. It seems happen here: `(ff_compute_frame_duration+60)`